# Progressbar color issue, strange acting

Tags: android, colors, progress-bar

This is a screen of my progressbar. Well not always but sometimes it acting strange like this. I mean instead to be in one color it get confused like this on the picture.
I do not do anything special I just update the progress...

Does anyone have this kind of experience with progressbars ?

[image]

I must mention that this progressbar has 3dip for layout_height property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made factory data reset on the phone and that fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well afrer setProgress(something); I also done invalidate(); so this thing helps avoiding this kind of wired problems