# TextView after rotating: are these problems bugs?

Tags: android, textview, rotation

I've created 2 TextView. One of them was rotated to 30 degrees from vertical. Another one was rotated to 40 degrees from vertical.

There are 2 problems:

1. While I set fixed typeface and fixed text size to these views, it
   looks like they have different text sizes. Why?
2. When I set text to textViews, it sometimes depicted broken. And
       only for rotated views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't guess you problem, cause you do not provide code, nor layouts ....

But in cases like this it is useful to do this

textview.invalidate();

this is method that sometimes really helps when you have complex drawrings. cause the sometimes components are lazy and they do not update them self.

Comment: View invalidates automatically, cause I rotate an arrow and update textViews.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262171/progressbar-color-issue-strange-acting I had that problem, I made factory reset and I thought solved but it showed again , in the end I solved with invalidate

Comment: It's pity, I call invalidate every 0.4 sec. And sometimes text becomes broken.

Comment: 0.4 it is too often I think, maybe you should call invalidate only ones, only after some change on the textview. I mean after you change things than call invalidate()

Comment: please let mi know what did fix your problem I am interested in :)

Comment: I've refused from TextViews, I draw the text by Canvas. It has solved the problem with "different text size" (actually, there was anti-aliasing by Android system, so the text was appeared with different sizes). Unfortunately, I didn't solve myself the problem of broken text, but I decompiled one application and found that they use SurfaceView for drawing - and, their text isn't broken.